# How to remove SWT.MAX in setShellStyle method from WizardDialog class in JFace

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface

In WizardDialog class of Eclipse JFace in the run methods setShellStyle method is getting called. I want to remove default SWT.RESIZE and SWT.MAX flag setting. How to remove? How to edit the WizardDialog class.

Comment: Is this a `WizardDialog` that you are creating or are you asking about an existing wizard that Eclipse is creating?

Comment: i am asking about existing one

Comment: Any particular existing wizard? It may be possible to do something for a few of the wizards (out of the > 125 wizard I see in my Eclipse).

Comment: sorry. I am creating a new wizard pages. I am adding the wizard pages in a class. From that class i am calling another classs in which the instance for the wizarddialog is created

Answer (score 1):

`WizardDialog` calls `setShellStyle` in its constructor so if you are creating the dialog you can override the settings by calling `setShellStyle` again in a subclass:

```java
public class WizardDialogEx extends WizardDialog
{
  public WizardDialogEx(final Shell parentShell, final IWizard wizard)
  {
    super(parentShell, wizard);

    setShellStyle(style);
  }
}


WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialogEx(shell, wizard);

dialog.open();
```

The default style flags used by `WizardDialog` are:

```java
SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MAX | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.RESIZE
```

plus the current orientation style.

I do not think it is possible to change the style of wizard dialogs that Eclipse creates internally.

Update:
On some platforms these style flags are only taken as a hint and the window manager may override them.

Comment: hi, but im getting  the method setshellstyle from window is invisible error

Comment: Hi, sorry should have used a subclass, code revised